# Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day" - Only used one time today... why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day"

Only used one time today... why?

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */

// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 32; // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10);
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailSent = row[3];  //This puts email sent in column 3 so no duplicates
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
          //message content  '/xa0' is space, 'r\n\' is new line
    var emailAddress = "ron.shippers@metrogates.com" ; //email address
    var message = row[4] + '\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' +'\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' +'\xa0' +row[1] + '\r\n' +' \r\n' +' \r\n'+'' + '\r\n'+ '\r\n' +'DATE items to be picked up or delivered by:' + '\r\n' +'\r\n' + row[2] + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +'Vehicle to be used:' + '\xa0\xa0' + row[3] + '\r\n'+ '\r\n' + '\r\n'+ '\r\n'+'\r\n'+'Products/Parts to be picked up or delivered:' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +row[5];
    var subject = 'New Pickup & Delivery Request from enter code here****';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You say `var emailSent=row[3];  //This puts email sent in column 3 so no duplicates` but row[3] is getting it's data from column4

Comment: And then you write 'sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);` to column3.  So your writing EMAIL_SENT to column 3 but your reading it from column4 so this will not stop duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Besides the observations made by Cooper, the question doesn't include enough detail to explain the error message assuming that you only ran the function one time. By one side I think that the error message is not complete and the executions are not shown and it's not mentioned if this is the only script that you have or if you have more scripts. Also it doesn't include a brief description of the search/research efforts made so far as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi ! Has this error occurred on several occassions or only once? Have you tried running it on several days? If so, did this still happened? (I tried to reproduce your isssue but my code with you and @Cooper function run both perfectly).

Answer (score 1):

This should stop your duplicate issue assuming everything else is correct.

```
var EMAIL_SENT='EMAIL_SENT';
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow=2;
  var numRows=32;
  var dataRange=sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 10);
  var data=dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i< data.length;++i) {
    var row=data[i];
    var emailSent=row[2];//modified
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) {
    var emailAddress="email address" ;
    var message=row[4] + '\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' +'\xa0' + '\xa0' +'\xa0' +'\xa0' +row[1] + '\r\n' +' \r\n' +' \r\n'+'' + '\r\n'+ '\r\n' +'DATE items to be picked up or delivered by:' + '\r\n' +'\r\n' + row[2] + '\r\n' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +'Vehicle to be used:' + '\xa0\xa0' + row[3] + '\r\n'+ '\r\n' + '\r\n'+ '\r\n'+'\r\n'+'Products/Parts to be picked up or delivered:' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +row[5];
    var subject='New Pickup & Delivery Request from enter code here****';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
 }
}
```